# Issue with finding the bounds of integer occurrence in a sorted array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, binary-search

I am trying to find the bounds for a key within a **sorted** array. For example, the function takes in an array and a key, and returns the lower and upper bounds based on the contents of the array and the key given (e.g. `public static int [] boundFinder`).

The lower bound will be the lowest index where the key occurs, and the upper bound will be the highest index where the key occurs. Here is an example input with the proper output:

*Sorted array: { 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 14, 40 }*

*Key: 5*

*Output: 3, 7*

In my code, I am using binary search since the array is sorted. However, I am easily able to get the upper bound, but continuously have issues with getting the lower bound. I understand I could modify my binary search method, but have tried to use Java's Math library to get the proper min and max for my bounds. I also stored my result into an array to return back to the user.

Please let me know if my approach could be improved (code below). I was wondering if I could potentially use a different data structure or algorithm to solve this problem at an optimal speed? I understand I could always loop over the entire array but that would not be the best.

Thank you in advance!

```
public static int[] boundFinder(int[] array, int key) {
    int [] resultArr = new int[2];

    int floorIndex = -1;
    int ceilingIndex = array.length;

    while (floorIndex + 1 < ceilingIndex) {
        resultArr[0] = Math.min(resultArr[0], binarySearch(array, floorIndex, ceilingIndex, key));
        resultArr[1] = Math.max(resultArr[1], binarySearch(array, floorIndex, ceilingIndex, key));
        floorIndex++;
    }

    return resultArr;
}

public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int floorIndex, int ceilingIndex, int key) {
    while (floorIndex + 1 < ceilingIndex) {
        int distance = ceilingIndex - floorIndex;
        int halfDistance = distance/2;
        int guessIndex = floorIndex + halfDistance;

        int guessValue = array[guessIndex];

        if (guessValue == key) {
            return guessIndex;
        } else if (guessValue > key) {
            ceilingIndex = guessIndex;
        } else {
            floorIndex = ceilingIndex;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic works for upper (right) bound, because you are continuously increasing the lower start index of the array and when you reach the last index of the element where element is present, the binary search will find the element and return.

The same logic will not work for lower (left) bound because you return immediately after the finding the element. Once you reach the last index where element is present, it will always return `0` and that is what happening.

The major of disadvantage of your approach is number of `binarysearch` method call are equal to the number of element in the array. So the complexity of the algorithm become `O(n log (n))`. This is worse than `O(n)`, which you can achieve by simple linear search.

---

You need to write two separate implementation for getting the `left most` and `right most` index of the element in array.

Because once you find the element in the array, you need to move either right or left to find the boundary index of the element. The logic for moving into either end boundary is different than other.

---

Once you find the element, check the left side of the index, if that also equal to the key, then call the search again.

```
public static int leftSearch(int a[], int key, int l, int h) {
  if (l<=h) {
    int mid = (l+h)/2;
    if (a[mid] == key) {
      if (mid > 0 && a[mid-1] == key) {
        return leftSearch(a, key, l, mid-1);
      } else {
        return mid;
      }
    }
    if (a[mid] > key) {
      return leftSearch(a, key, l, mid-1);
    } else {
      return leftSearch(a, key, mid+1, h);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

---

Once you find the element, check the right side of the index, if that is also equal then call the search again.

```
public static int rightSearch(int a[], int key, int l, int h) {
  if (l<=h) {
    int mid = (l+h)/2;
    if (a[mid] == key) {
      if (mid<h && a[mid+1] == key) {
        return rightSearch(a, key, mid + 1, h);
      } else {
        return mid;
      }
    }
    if (a[mid] > key) {
      return rightSearch(a, key, l, mid-1);
    } else {
      return rightSearch(a, key, mid+1, h);
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

---

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int array[] = new int[]{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 14, 40 };
  int leftIndex = leftSearch(array, 5, 0, array.length-1);
  System.out.println(leftIndex);
  int rightIndex = rightSearch(array, 5, 0, array.length-1);
  System.out.println(rightIndex);
}
```

output:

```
3
7
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just show you a method which clicked me:

```
int min=-1; int max=0;
public int[] boundFinder(int[] array,int key)
{
    int[] resultArray=new int[2];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
   if(array[i]==key)
{
     max=i;
     if(min==-1)//so that only lower bound is assigned to min.
     {
         min=i;
      }
}
}
 resultArray[0]=min;  //stores the bounds
 resultArray[1]=max;
 return resultArray;
}
```

The value of `min` will be changed only once since we are using the `if` statement.But `max` will have the final or the highest bound value.Finally,I have stored these values in an array(`resultArray`) and returned it.

- If you want to make it more simpler,you could try using `array list` which has some pre-defined functions to return the index.

Comment: This can be achieved by using binary search with two separate implementation for calculating left and right bounds of the array.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Yes of course.There are many ways to do it.I was just trying to make it simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your binary search as below to achieve your requirement ...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9, 14, 40 };
        //int[] array = { 1, 2, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10 };
        int key = 5; 

        int len = array.length;

        int [] resultArr = new int[2];
        resultArr[0]=0;
        resultArr[1]=len-1;


        while(!(array[resultArr[0]]==key && array[resultArr[1]]==key)){
            int mid = (resultArr[0]+resultArr[1])/2;
            if(array[mid]>key){
                    resultArr[1] = mid-1;
            }
            else if (array[mid]<key){
                    resultArr[0]=mid+1;
            }
            else{
                if(array[resultArr[1]]!=key){
                    resultArr[1]=resultArr[1]-1;
                }
               else if (array[resultArr[0]]!=key)
                    resultArr[0]=resultArr[0]+1;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("LowerBoundary - "+resultArr[0]+" UpperBoundary - "+resultArr[1]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than two separate binary search implementations, use a single binary search implementation that always finds the leftmost occurrence. Call it once with `key` to find the first occurrence, and then call it a second time with `key+1` to find the first occurrence of a number *after* `key`. You want to subtract 1 from the result returned by the second call.

So your `boundFinder` method does this (assuming you're using Java's built-in [binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) method):

```
int min = binarySearch(array, key);
int max = binarySearch(array, key+1) - 1;
```

This assumes that both `key` and `key+1` are in the array. If you can't assume that `key+1` is in the array, then you would write:

```
int max;
int next = binarySearch(array, key+1);
if (next < 0)
{
    max = -key - 1;
}
else
{
    max = key-1;
}
// fill your result array with min and max
```